# Laptop Suggestions - Long Term Upgrade

Tags: laptop

I am looking for suggestions for laptops (ultrabooks are also okay, as long as they meet the requirements):

The requirements are the following:

- Intel Kaby Lake "8th" Gen
- Minimum 16GB, if it can be expanded to 32GB even better
- NVMe 512 minimum, 1TB if it can be upgraded
- Windows precision drivers for trackpad

So far, I am able to find a few that match the above, however, the next part is where I am having difficulties:

- nVidia 1060/1070; or some other video configuration that will allow me to play medium requirement games (like WoW and other Blizzard titles) at maximum quality without clipping or lag.
- 14" maximum display size - I need to carry it everyday, so a heavy 15" is out of the question, unless its very portable.
- Should be minimum full-hd, if its QHD or UHD even better
- Touch / Pen is not a requirement
- Matte display (nice to have, but if it has some other form of anti-glare then its okay, what I absolutely don't want is a glossy display)
- Must be able to sustain at least 7 hours on battery
- Backlit keyboard
- Reliable build
- USB-C charging
- Thunderbolt 3.1 (dual channel support - the maximum bandwidth possible)
- Must be able to support 32" (3840x2160 resolution) monitor with DP

So far what I have looked at:

- 13" Dell XPS

  - I currently use the previous edition of this laptop (the non 8th gen), everything is okay except in less than a year I have had to replace the battery and the keyboard; plus my unit has some finishing issues like it will not sit level on the desk. I am not sold on the fit and finish of it either.
- Surface Book

  - I almost settled on the 15" one since its portable enough, but then I read reviews that the USB-C is only half-width and that the power adapter cannot charge the device if you are utilizing the hardware fully (especially with the dedicated VGA)
- X1 Carbon / Yoga

  - A few colleagues have these, but the CPU + GPU is not what I want; other than that these are great
- Razer 14 / Blade

  - Not sure about the build quality of these or if they are suitable.

Comment: I'll work on a more complete answer, but why do you specifically want a Kaby Lake processor specifically? Would a last-gen quad core be fine? 7 hours of battery life may be a bit tricky (if you use real world numbers instead of the manufacture ones.) Do you have any concerns with budget? You mentioned portability is an issue for you; how heavy is too heavy? There's a pretty big range in the weight of 15" laptops.

Comment: A GTX 1060/1070 isn't going to be able to max out every Blizzard title, but I think I get your idea regarding the performance you're looking at. What's your opinion on eGPUs?

Comment: I think you're going to have an awfully hard time finding a matte display in this day and age, with Macs having glossy as (basically) always, and many other manufacturers moving towards glossy touchscreens. Anti-glare of some sort is pretty common, though performance varies widely; would an aftermarket cover satisfy you?

Comment: I'm of the opinion all four of the laptops you listed are good, but none of them quite meet your requirements. XPS 13 fails graphics card and matte display (though I've never seen build quality issues, so it might have been a one-off bad experience for you or just me being misinformed); Surface Book fails to have a good enough graphics card (GTX 1050), matte display, backlit keyboard, and (as you mentioned) Thunderbolt 3; X1 Carbon (and the Yoga line is pretty massive) fails Kaby Lake and GPU...

Comment: [Razer Blade 14](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1GABTei_7c) doesn't fail build quality (though it may fail reliability), matte display and Kaby Lake.

Comment: I already have laptops with the 7th gen, and some of the work that I do would really benefit from the extra cores. I am willing to pay premium for the right device, as I don't plan on updating it for at least 3 years. Right now I carry the Dell XPS 13 and Macbook Pro (lightbar 15"). The macbook pro is heavy for me to lug around all day (I cant' really wear a backpack to work).

Comment: A matte display is a requirement because my work requires me to type a lot and staring back at my own reflection or fighting glare from lights, or having to use it outside on a sunny day - all these fall by the wayside on a glossy display.

Comment: As of now though there are no hexa-core mobile processors, so a quad-core 7th gen should be just fine. I'm missing though why you're carrying two laptops instead of one, if your goal is to keep things light.

Comment: If matte is that important and you don't want to use an aftermarket cover, I think you're basically going to be forced towards the ThinkPad line if you want a fairly light notebook. Almost every notebook these days uses a glossy display.

Comment: The work that I am doing right now requires macosx; but I am transiting away from that role. So in the end, there will only be one laptop. I was trying to convey that the 15" macbook pro feels heavy to me to be carrying around (well obviously the dell xps 13 is a much more manageable device). In the end the goal is to have one device.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71172/discussion-between-jmy1000-and-burhan-khalid).